# Replace hash arguments with one has object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have many models need to include `has_attached_file` with the identical arguments

How can I store the arguments in one hash object?

## Current usage

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :cover,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    :s3_host_name => ENV['S3_HOST'],
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml" ,
    :styles => IMAGE_STYLES,
    :default_url => "/images/missing.png"

end
```

## Expected usage

```
default_s3_arguments = {:storage => :s3,
        :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
        :s3_host_name => ENV['S3_HOST'],
        :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml" ,
        :styles => IMAGE_STYLES,
        :default_url => "/images/missing.png"}


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :cover, default_s3_arguments

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a constant which i believe it is,

You can define the hash in an initializer like this

**DO THIS ONLY IF YOU WOULD NEED TO USE THIS HASH IN OTHER MODELS**

```
S3_ARGUMENTS = {:storage => :s3,
                :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
                :s3_host_name => ENV['S3_HOST'],
                :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml" ,
                :styles => IMAGE_STYLES,
                :default_url => "/images/missing.png"}
```

Then within your Model you can use it like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :cover, S3_ARGUMENTS

end
```

If you don't need this in other Models, then define the constant in your class Model itself.

Comment: I'd suggest removing `DEFAULT` from the name, since strictly speaking and according to how we generally use that word in Ruby, it is not really a default, but rather a common set of options.  (That is, the reader seeing 'DEFAULT' might look for different data used and a default argument specification.  Instead, a name describing at a high level the set of options would be helpful, or, if not, simply S3_ARGUMENTS or FILE_ATTACHED_ARGUMENTS or something like that.

Comment: @KeithBennett Yes i totally agree, i was just using the same name that the OP used. btw, i've updated the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at the paperclip S3 documentation if that is what you are using

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3